# Как зашифровать строку на фронте, что бы потом расшифровать на беке?

Tags: php, шифрование

Есть строка вида
`site.name/ck/{resource_name}?data={id}&trc={token}`

выглядит это так

`http://site.name/ck/blabla?data=22248&trc=x5jH0h8xUX6Gd6h1AYZEaY2VrVCpQSiuBW0oIEfQ`

Как можно зашифровать (что бы только сервер мог расшифровать) передаваемые параметры `data` и `trc` что бы потом можно было расшифровать их на бекэнде?

UPD: Сама задача в том, что бы посетитель переходя по зашифрованной ссылке, передаваемые данные расшифровывались на сервере и обрабатывались, создавался новый обьект, и возвращал посетителю некие данные основанные на переданных данных. Суть в том, что бы нельзя было подменить айди передаваемый посетителем. для этого и хочу шифровать его

Comment: Например RSA...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Не могли бы вы привести пример?

Comment: вам надо будет использовать JavaScript. такое решение подходит?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman если данные нельзя будит расшифровать на фронте (при отключенном js или еще как то), то подходит

Comment: @Alex_01 без JavaScript будет сложно зашифровать данные

Comment: Если шифровать на клиенте, то пользователь зашифрует что захочет как захочет, и это вы не обойдёте никак. Если вам надо защитить данные, которые присылает сервер, то сервером же и зашифруйте и потом отправляйте серверу зашифрованные им же данные. А вообще лучше расскажите конкретнее, что именно и почему вы хотите шифровать, вдруг там шифровать ничего и не нужно

Comment: вам, похоже, нужно не шифрование, а mac

Answer (score 1):

Если задача защитить данные от человека-по-середине(MITM), то самый действенный способ - использование уровня защищенных сокетов(SSL). Для этого нужно будет обзавестись закрытым ключом, а клиенту отправить сертификат(публичный ключ). Детали реализации тут нет смысла перечислять - все это инкапсулировано внутри протокола прикладного уровня HTTPS. Поэтому для использования этой технологии достаточно убедиться в том, что ваш хостер поддерживает запросы по протоколу HTTPS.

Более простой вариант(если постоянная защита от MITM`а не требуется, но есть некоторый маленький объем передаваемого трафика, который хотелось бы защитить), то в таком случае, решения нет. По крайней мере, безопасного. Нет по той причине, что любая информация, зашифрованная на стороне клиента(любой криптографический алгоритм, его ключи и т.д) является достоянием общественности - алгоритм ее шифрования априори известен каждому, кто умеет пользоваться клавишей F12(и подобными). Однако в силе остается метод, озвученный в 1 абзаце - открытая криптография. Но в таком случае, опять же, с сервера клиенту нужно будет сначала отправить публичный ключ, что уже реализовано в автоматическом режиме на уровне SSL/TLS - "разблокировать" такой шифр сможет либо сервер, либо ПО, которому удалось получить доступ к информации до применения к ней открытого ключа.

P.S
Насчет

> "Суть в том, что бы нельзя было подменить айди передаваемый
>   посетителем. для этого и хочу шифровать его"

..то просто примите как должное, что все данные, отправляемые клиентом, с вероятностью, близкой к единице, будут изменяться перехватчиком. Поэтому просто реализуйте безопасную логику на стороне сервера, которая не доверяет клиенту.

Comment: Сам алгоритм шифрования не гарантирует, что его знание позволит дешифровать данные http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86595/why-cant-you-work-backwards-with-public-key-to-decrypt-a-message

Другое дело, что данные, находящиеся в рантайме, вытаскиваются куда более легкими способами

Comment: Ну и сам сертификат и есть публичный ключ

Comment: @Etki, речь в том топике про односторонние функции, безопасное использование которых возможно лишь в случае ассиметричной криптографии, о которой я и написал выше. Если есть общий секрет, который будет передаваться клиенту(значение степени, соль и т.д), то это, очевидно,небезопасно. Знание самогО алгоритма нередко безопасно, но это же знание + используемые входные параметры - небезопасно.

Answer (score 0):

Кто не должен дешифровать данные?

- Если вы хотите защитить канал связи (MITM etc) , то переместите данные в entity-body и включите SSL. Никто кроме сервера эти данные не прочтет.
- Если вы не хотите явно передавать эти данные, то генерируйте хэш от этих параметров на сервере, сохраняйте данные в табличку(используя хэш как уникальный идентификатор). На клиенте у вас будет ссылка вида:
  http://site.name/ck/blabla?hash=my_hash_func

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Что требуется

Answer (score -4):

Значит, саму эту ссылку должен зашифровать сервер.

Любые данные от клиента можно подменить.

Comment: Минусаторы, а чем собственно ответ не устраивает?